# Babel require hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Starting a new project and I'm wanting to use ES6/2015 features with Node.  Currently trying use the [babel-core require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/#usage).  This seems simple enough, but my required modules are throwing syntax errors.

App entry point:

```
require("babel-core/register")({
    ignore: false
});

var app = require('app/app');
...
```

Required file (app/app.js):

```
// this SHOULD be compiled by the Babel require hook
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => res.render('page/page', {}));
```

Syntax Error:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => res.render('page/page', {}));
                              ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
```

Babel-core: 6.1.21

I am sure I am missing something really simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310149/people-constantly-use-babel-instead-of-babeljs-shouldnt-we-do-something-ab?cb=1

Comment: @garakchy thank you sir.

Comment: fat array is supported after node v4.0, so you can use that out of box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel core needs a preset to transform something. If you want to use ES2015, this preset is called *babel-preset-es2015*.

Add this preset to your project : `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

With babel 6 you also need to create a `.babelrc` file in your root folder.
Add *es2015* to use babel-preset-es2015.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! For anyone else who is interested I found this [setting up babel 6](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/) guide.  Thanks!